# Cannot use Where condition in Array columns

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a column which is of an `array` type. I want to use the `where` condition in my script, but am unable to. The unnest formula is too complex to use and I want to keep it simple here.

I have 4 columns. One of them is called `box_number`. It can have an array of multiple numbers. I want to search for rows where `box_number` contains `123`.

```
select
*
from BOX_TABLE
where box_number is {123}
```

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM BOX_TABLE WHERE 123 = ANY (box_number);
```

You check that at least one value inside the column is 123.

Answer (score 3):

To test for equality, try

```
WHERE box_number = ARRAY[123]
```

To test if the array contains your value, use the “contains” operator `&&`:

```
WHERE box_number && ARRAY[123]
```